# Pass Jquery datatable search result to ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I need to pass data from Jquery datatable to an ASP.NET MVC controller on button click. It should be whole table by default or the result of filtering.

I have tried many things. My code now look as follows. The main problem is that I do not understand what do I have to pass to controller. Is there a way to do it without creating a special view model and just pass some the Generic (array of Object) the way i am trying to do ?

```
 var tableData;   
    $(document).ready(function () {          
            var  table =   $('#MySelector').DataTable({
            processing: false,
            destroy: true,
            searching: true,
            paging: true,
            info: true,

            initComplete: function () {



                this.api().columns([0, 1, 2, 3,]).every(function () {

                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<br><select class = "form-control" ' + '><option value="" >--Select--</option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.header()))
                        .on('click', function (e) { console.log(" click on select in column =" + column.data()); e.stopPropagation(); })
                        .on('search.dt', function () {

                        })
                        .on('change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );                      

                            column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
                        });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {

                        if (d !== null && d !== '') {
                            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                        }
                    });
                });
            },

            ajax: {
                url: "/MyController/MyGetMethod",
                "type": "GET",
                dataSrc: function (json) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(json.resultD);

                    return obj;
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "EmployeeID" },
                { data: "Name" },
                { data: "Email" },
                { data: "Department" }                              
            ]
        });

         table.on('search.dt', function () {          
          tableData = table.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).data();
        })

    });



function passDatatableToController() {                        
       tableData = table.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).data();   
        var model = JSON.stringify(tableData);     
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Reports/ExportReport/',
            data: model,
       success: function(responseData){           
        }
    });

    }

//Controller
public ActionResult ExportReport(Object[] data)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Seems backwards. If you used server side processing options to start with you would have each set of search  results at the server before they get rendered client side

Comment: I just  need some functionality that will grab dt rows that I currently see on the screen and pass it to the controller.

Comment: So where are you having specific problems?

Comment: I either cannot hit the controller at all. Or I can hit it and get all nulls in array. To get datatable data into variable upon filtering doesn't seem to be a problem. i do it bytableData = table.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).data(); . But how I can pass it to controller and what parameters I put as an argument

Comment: It's been a while since I went through the event flow for things like `.on('search.dt'`. Not sure if it fires after all the data is filtered or not. The docs should spell that out. Other than that would need a lot more specifics regrading debugging you have done to help out more. In other words it's not clear if you have a problem within the plugin callbacks or only in ajax or in structuring the data to send or ??

Comment: I believe the problem is with structuring data and sending it  .on('search.dt'.)  I get an array of objects resulting from filtering.  So let's simplify a problem to how to properly send an array of objects to controller

Comment: Just Stringify the whole array and send as json

Comment: ok if tableData is my array of object and i do JSON.stringify(tableData);  How should my controller agrument look like    public ActionResult ExportReport(List<Object> data)?

Comment: I'm at a bit of  loss there since I know very little about .Net. I only replied since all the code shown is javascript/jQuery. Should be easy enough to research how to receive json though since it is a very very common practice